# Remove stamp on an existing pdf

Tags: .net, pdf, itext

I am using to iTextSharp to create a PDF, all it does is read the source pdf file (S_PDF.pdf), stamps some text on top and bottom of that document and save result as file (R_PDF.PDF).

Now, i have a requirement that says, remove stamps from R_PDF.pdf file and compare that with S_PDF.pdf.

I kind of doubt on that requirement (why do we really need to compare the same file). But i was asked to find out if it is possible. So i did little search on google and was able to remove stamps using ASPOSE (Could not find something from iText to remove stamps on existing pdf docs), anyway now questions are:

- how to compare these files? just boolean type result is good enough
- can we use iText to remove all or specific stamps?

Comment: I assume you want to only see the *visual* differences between *"S.pdf"* and *"R.pdf which has watermark removed again"*? That is, differences in the *rendered* PDFs, not differences in their internal file structure?

Comment: My Client wants to know if the stamping process cut off some thing. So yes your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [i-net PDF content comparer](http://www.inetsoftware.de/other-products/pdf-content-comparer) seems to have a good [api](http://www.inetsoftware.de/documentation/other-products/pdf-content-comparer/apispec/index.html) as well.

Another option that I use more often is [diff-pdf](http://vslavik.github.com/diff-pdf/), best part with this is, it compares files visually - that helps reducing a lot of encoding noise.

Check out [Docotic.Pdf Library](http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/), it should allow you to [compare using VB.NET](http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/help/check-that-two-pdf-documents-are-equal.aspx).

Comment: Can we use these to compare files using VB.NET ?

Comment: Thank you, looks promising, will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. We have:

1. S_PDF
2. R_PDF

How about:

**Step One:** S_PDF => iTextSharp => "New R_PDF".

**Step Two:** Comparison R_PDF and "New S_PDF" byte by byte? In this case you can use any file comparison tool.

Comment: Well, I am looking for a tool to compare two file. do you know any such tool set ?

Comment: Personally me - not, but wikipedia knows! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools